# Django 1.4 - Manually import admin models

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Related to [my earlier question in regards extending Django's AdminSite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341663/django-override-admin-sites-login-form/11347302), I have sucessfully subclassed AdminSite and can log in perfectly fine. However, my admin site has no application models in it! The admin.autodiscover() function no longer works, and I'm simply not skilled enough with Python to figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Long story short, if I cannot use AdminSite.autodiscover(), how do I load all of the models in my verious Django apps into my subclassed AdminSite instance?

Comment: If you could show us the code how you override the `AdminSite` it'll help us understand why its not working.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3206933/113962) to a similar stack overflow question should help.

Comment: Ah, of course, how stupid of me. I'll edit this shortly with a couple of code snippets. (I'm clearly way too tired today!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason not to use the [`django.contrib.admin.autodiscover`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py), even if you subclassed `AdminSite`. This is the actual instrumentation that imports the `admin` module from  all your Django applications registered in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`, effectively registering the models with your admin site instance.

To recap if you have a `project.admin.foo_site` instance of your `project.admin.FooAdminSite` subclass:

```
# project/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from project.admin import foo_site


admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(foo_site.urls)),
)

#project/app/admin.py
from project.admin import foo_site
from project.app.models import Bar


foo_site.register(Bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [set up an admin.py and register your models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin).  Here's a paraphrased version from the Django Tutorial:

> To do this, create a file called admin.py in your app directory, and
>   edit it to look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import Model1, Model2, Model3

admin.site.register(Model1)
admin.site.register(Model2)
admin.site.register(Model3)
```

Comment: I think he's not just talking about custom apps but also Django's contrib apps models not showing.

Comment: Sorry yes, it's all apps, not just my own. Django's contrib apps aren't showing either.