# Using an alternative authentication backend for Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, cas

I'm using CAS for authentication on my Django site (via django-cas-ng). If I log in through CAS and then visit the admin site, it works fine, but if I visit the admin site when not logged in, it redirects to the admin site's login form instead of to the CAS login page. How can I make it redirect to the CAS login page instead?

Comment: something similar to this may work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341663/django-override-admin-sites-login-form

Comment: Adding django-cas-ng middleware to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES did the trick for me (the doc of the project is not clear on that point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I ended up dealing with this was by subclassing `AdminSite` and overriding `admin_view`, `login`, and `logout`. Instead of redirecting unauthorized users to the admin interface's login view, `admin_view` now redirects anonymous users to `settings.LOGIN_URL`, and raises `PermissionDenied` for authenticated users who aren't staff. `login` and `logout` are now simply redirects to `settings.LOGIN_URL` and `settings.LOGOUT_URL`.

I put my code to do this [on GitHub](https://github.com/TaymonB/django-admin-external-auth/blob/master/daeauth.py), and also uploaded it to PyPI under the name `django-admin-external-auth`, in case anyone else ever needs to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `'django_cas_ng.middleware.CASMiddleware'` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` will automatically redirect the user to the CAS login page instead of the django admin login form.

Example:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django_cas_ng.middleware.CASMiddleware',
    ...
)
```