# How to include forward slash in django username

Tags: django, django-users

I am working on a website that requires user username to include forward slash. something like 'CSC/15U/1155' as username.

django says *'Enter a valid username. This value may contain only letters, numbers, and @/./+/-/_ characters.'*.

my question is as follows: is there a way to allow forward slash in username without extending the user model, if there is please help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, just trying to help. Official docs says you [should subclass `User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.username_validator) with a `Meta CustomUser`.

Answer (score 2):

This error is occurring because of [Django's Username validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.username_validator). So you can override it like this(Copy Pasted from documentation):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.validators import ASCIIUsernameValidator

class CustomUser(User):
    username_validator = ASCIIUsernameValidator()  # or your custom validator

    class Meta:
        proxy = True  # If no new field is added.
```

Or if you don't want to use any validators, then just [override the username field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD).

### Update

When you are using `CustomUser` model, you need to update `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py`. For example:

```
#  settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.models.CustomUser'
```

And if you want to override the `username` field in `CustomUser`, then you can do it like this:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


 class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
      username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Please see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/) on how to use custom User model in Django.

For adminsite, you need to override your login form. For example:

```
# some form

from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='username', max_length=100)
```

And update in urls.py([as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341663/django-override-admin-sites-login-form)):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from my.forms import AuthenticationForm

admin.autodiscover()
admin.site.login_form = LoginForm
```

Default adminsite login does not work because it uses [Username](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L60) field which normalizes the input value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i still cannot create username containing forward slash. i think **ASCIIUsernameValidator** is only allowing letters, numbers, and @/./+/-/_ characters.'. in my case i wants to allow  forward slash '/'

Comment: In that case, just override the username field like the documentation mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I overrides the username the validator now it works in the shell with User.objects.create_user() but unfortunately it does not work with django admin form