# How to customize Django-Jazzmin login pages

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using django-jazzmin package to customize the django-admin interface. However, I would like to have my own login form along with a password reset option. I've created the corresponding templates under `templates/registration/` directory and added the corresponding url patterns to the `url.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^.*password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(subject_template_name='registration/html_password_reset_subject.txt',
    html_email_template_name='registration/html_password_reset_email.html'), name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^.*password_reset/done/$', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),    
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
    url(r'^.*logout/$', logout,{'next_page': 'myapp:login'}),
    url(r'^.*accounts/login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),
    url(r'^.*accounts/profile/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/profile.html'), name='profile'),
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
]
```

However, I still get the Jazzmin login form.

Any ideas?

Comment: override jazzmin login is just like override django normal login page, take a look at this answer it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/32539459/11225821. If you just want to customize the template not the view override admin/login.html template like jazzmin does https://github.com/farridav/django-jazzmin/blob/master/jazzmin/templates/admin/login.html